# Change "selected" on scroll in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to get the automatic update on my navbar but i cant get it to work. 
Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/YTHaBD0i

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="download selected"><a href="#firstPage">Download</a></li>
    <li class="features"><a href="#secondPage">Features</a></li>
    <li class="method"><a href="#3rdPage">Method</a></li>
    <li class="purchase"><a href="#4thPage">Purchase</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="footer">yey productions &copy; 2016</div>

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section " id="section0">
    <div class="intro">
      <h1>Download</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section1">
    <div class="slide" id="slide1">
      <div class="intro">
        <h1>Features</h1>
        <p>Cheese.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide2">
      <h1>Cheese2</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section2">
    <div class="intro">
      <h1>Yey</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section3">
    <div class="intro">
      <h1>Yey2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Greetz,

Comment: Hou should be more precise on your question.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using jQuery, you will need a function that [fires every time you scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/).

From there, you need to detect which elements are in view.

Once you know which elements are in view, clear any currently active elements with the `.selected` class, then choose which one you want to be `.selected` and add the `.selected` class.

*Edit for more detail:*

Below is a pure JavaScript solution, which I found [here](http://codepen.io/zchee/pen/ogzvZZ). This should be close to a drop-in solution!:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
  var sections = {};
  var i = 0;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(section, function(e) {
    sections[e.id] = e.offsetTop;
  });

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i in sections) {
      if (sections[i] <= scrollPosition) {
        document.querySelector('.selected').setAttribute('class', ' ');
        document.querySelector('a[href*=' + i + ']').setAttribute('class', 'selected');
      }
    }
  };
})();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks, I added some more detail, which I hope is sufficient!